# Database Trigger doesn't save

Tags: database, triggers, sql-server-2014, database-trigger

I'm new to triggers. I'm trying to write a trigger using sql server 2014. here is my code

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteTrigger
ON student
FOR DELETE
AS
DELETE FROM [stu-course] 
where [stu-course].sid in ( select deleted.sid  from deleted )
GO
```

i right click on Database Triggers in the path myDataBase ->Programmability ->Database Triggers and select New Database Trigger and write my code there. but it doesn't save; and when i click on Database Triggers again , there is no sign of my trigger. what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried refresh refreshing the Object Explorer? Right click on `Database Triggers` and choose `Refresh`.

Comment: @ZoffDino I tried everything that you can name now. refresh , restart , close & open , ...   none worked.

Comment: Dumb question... but did you execute the `CREATE TRIGGER` script?

Comment: @ZoffDino yes, that didn't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't find it under the `database triggers` folder is that it's a DML trigger, **not** a database trigger (these are only DDL triggers).

Note the [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) page on MSDN:

> Server-scoped DDL triggers appear in the SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer in the Triggers folder. This folder is located under the Server Objects folder. Database-scoped DDL Triggers appear in the Database Triggers folder. This folder is located under the Programmability folder of the corresponding database.

If you have executed the create trigger script, and did not get any errors (the syntax looks ok to me), you should find it under the triggers folder of the `student` table.

However, the operation you are attempting to do using this trigger would be better handled by using the [`on delete cascade`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on the [foreign key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx) constraint between the `students` table and the `stu-course` table.